# initialize() or creationComplete() method not invoked when revisiting the page in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

In my flex application I use the viewstack.selectedchild() property to change the views.

When I revisit the views by the viewstack.selectedchild() property the initialize method doesnot get invoked..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object has already been created so it doesn't re-initialize it's already in memory (which is a good thing for the most part).  You want to listen for changes on the view stack's selected child anyway just add a listener to that instead and do you're logic in there if you want it every time the view is changed.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/ViewStack.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#event:change
alternatively you can probably use the show event within the object that's in the view stack to get the event when it changes from invisible to visible.

Comment: I change the viewstack.selectedchild in the main application and the viewstack objects are mxml components. How do I set the visible property of the mxml component from the main application ?

Comment: I have uploaded a snippet.. Hope tat helps!!

Comment: hmm I don't think I understand... if you have an mxml component and you just want to change the visible property you can just give the mxml component an id then you'd say myComponentId.visible = false or true... I think what you want is what do you do to get when this changes... in your custom MXML class just add a show property that will expect a function as a value and then it will call that function everytime the visible property is changed from false to true (whether by the view stack or by you programmatically).  Post some source if I'm going the wrong way. checking snippet now one sec

Comment: I am not able to paste the code.. Browser issues may be.. Here is the example I used.. http://htmlcoderhelper.com/flex-3-passing-data-from-modules-to-parent-application-to-switch-views-in-the-viewstack/.. Instead of modules.. I used navigatorContent..

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, by default, each view will get instantiated and initialized once when they are initially shown (same with creation complete.)  After that, switching between the views will not result in them being initialized again.  If you want to perform some sort of action whenever the selected view changes, you should attach a listener to your ViewStack for the mx.events.IndexChangedEvent.CHANGE event.  It would also be helpful to learn more about the flex component lifecycle (which includes initialization).  Here's a diagram I have found useful: http://danorlando.com/?p=122

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still too short on information to answer this completely what is the end goal, to have a view stack on the stage and know when the selected index changed you just do it like this:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="viewstack" width="100%" height="100%" change="changeHandler(event)">
    <s:NavigatorContent id="view1" label="view1">
    <views:view1 />
    </s:NavigatorContent>
<s:NavigatorContent id="view2" label="view2">
    <views:view2 />
</s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

in the changeHandler function you can use the event.selectedIndex property to know which one of the items is showing right now... or else you can look at the view1.visible property.  You can programatically change the one being shown by doing viewStack.selectedIndex = 0 or viewStack.selectedChild = view1.

Also if you want to know from within the component (like within view1's mxml) you can use the show property such as:

```
<views:view2 show="showHandler(event)"/>
```

Comment: In the change handler event in the main application, I programmatically change the selectedchild to the views that I want to display. but the showhandler is implemented in the view1 and view2 and not in the main application. How do I invoke them?? Is it possible to invoke the function defined in the mxml components from the main application?

Comment: Sorry I missed that comment, was just perusing old posts and saw this, I hope you were able to get it working but yes you can call methods so long as they are public from any component which contains your MXML component(in this case the application).  If you wish to have a method fired in the application from the MXML files you can use Application.application, or better still dispatch an event from your MXML child component and listen for the event in the application.  In short yes you can communicate between any objects you create regardless of MXML or AS (or SWF to SWF or javascript to SWF).

Answer (score 1):

The show() event of a component is dispatched when you pass from invisible to visible, 
so the following code DOES NOT work for a component contained in a viewstack

```
<s:NavigatorContent id="view1" label="view1">
 <views:view2 show="showHandler(event)"/>
</s:NavigatorContent>
```

In a viewStack component the simple way is to manage the change event
take the following MXML

```
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" change="onViewStackChange(event)">
 <s:NavigatorContent id="view1" label="view1_lbl">
  <views:view1 name="v1"/>
 </s:NavigatorContent>
 <s:NavigatorContent id="view2" label="view2_lbl">
  <views:view2 name="v2"/>
 </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

with this ActionScript Code

```
protected function onViewStackChange(event:IndexChangedEvent):void
{
    // alert label of selected nav content
    Alert.show("View Stack Change, Selected  = " + viewStack.selectedChild.label);

    // get selected nav content then show name of first child
    var navContent: NavigatorContent = (viewStack.selectedChild as NavigatorContent);
    Alert.show( "Change, 1st child is: " + navContent.getChildAt(0).name ); 
}
```

You can discriminate multiple components by labels

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

main.mxml

```
<mx:ViewStack id="viewstack" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:NavigatorContent id="view1" label="view1">
    <views:view1 />
    </s:NavigatorContent>
<s:NavigatorContent id="view2" label="view2">
    <views:view2 />
</s:NavigatorContent>
```

Comment: Rather than posting this as an answer, you should edit your existing question and append this to it. :)

Comment: Sure!! Will do that from the next time!!